# Capitalize last letter of a string

Tags: php, capitalization

How can I capitalize *only* the last letter of a string.

For example:

```
hello
```

becomes:

```
hellO
```

Comment: Of a string? You mean a paragraph/sentence/word? Otherwise, you're just doing an `strtoupper()` on the last position in a string variable that you control.

Comment: `echo strrev(ucfirst(strrev("hello")));` ;p

Comment: @karim79, that's much better than my idea, you should post it as an answer.

Comment: @Brad - done. I realised it might actually be worthwhile despite how it looks.

Answer (score 14):

Convoluted but fun:

```
echo strrev(ucfirst(strrev("hello")));
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/7QK5B

as a function:

```
function uclast($str) {
    return strrev(ucfirst(strrev($str)));
}
```

Comment: That works great! when I enter it just like that, but for what I'm trying to do is in wordpress change the page titles to all lowercase and the last letter uppercase. for example: right now the title shows up as Sample Page.  I want it to show up as sample pagE .  heres what I tried, but its not working `code`<?php
     $str= the_title();
     echo strrev(ucfirst(strrev($str)));
     ?>

Comment: @Kathy: `$str = strtolower(the_title());` first then.  If it doesn't work, there would likely be an error in your `the_title()` function.

Comment: ya you would think it would work.  I'm not sure why its not.  I would change all the page titles so they are entered with the cap at the end but i dont want it to show up that way in the navigation. I'm not sure how to do a cache break?? That link takes me to something about adsense.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Kathy - what Bob said. Sorry, I didn't get your comment. Just use `strtolower` first. Thanks @bob-the-destroyer.

Comment: better use `get_the_title()` to have a return value. `the_title()` will echo. Or do `the_title('','', false);` for the return value.

Comment: @bob-the-destroyer It's wordpress template tags. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title. edit - removed lecturing

Comment: @bob-the-destroyer - I think that's wordpress-speak.

Comment: Thanks guys, I think you're right. I think its the the_title() function.  I think its already capitalizing the first letter, so I'll see if i can find where it is and change it from there:) I'll let you know! Thanks again:)

Comment: @hakre thank you, using get_the_title() actually worked! so i didnt have to go look for the title function !! thanks again you guys..what an awesome forum.  I will be back i'm sure!

Answer (score 3):

When `$s` is your string ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/4N7N4)):

```
$s[-1] = strtoupper($s[-1]);
```

Or in form of a function:

```
function uclast(string $s): string
{
  $s[-1] = strtoupper($s[-1]);
  return $s;
}
```

And for your extended needs to have everything lower-case except the last character explicitly upper-case:

```
function uclast(string $s): string
{
  if ("" === $s) {
    return $s;
  }

  $s = strtolower($s);
  $s[-1] = strtoupper($s[-1]);

  return $s;
}
```

Comment: @Martijn: https://3v4l.org/15aT3 looks fine 8.0.0 - 8.0.9. and since 7.1.0 there is the -1 optimization, I should update the answer: https://3v4l.org/9Lj4c

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to this.  First, you need to know how to get parts of strings.  For that, you need the [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function.

Next, there is a function for capitalizing a string called [`strtotupper()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php).

```
$thestring="Testing testing 3 2 1. aaaa";
echo substr($thestring, 0, strlen($thestring)-2) . strtoupper(substr($thestring, -1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an algorithm:

```
  1. Split the string s = xyz where x is the part of
     the string before the last letter, y is the last
     letter, and z is the part of the string that comes
     after the last letter.
  2. Compute y = Y, where Y is the upper-case equivalent
     of y.
  3. Emit S = xYz
```

Answer (score 0):

Lowercase / uppercase / mixed character case for everything following can be used

```
<?php
    $word = "HELLO";

    //or

    $word = "hello";

    //or

    $word = "HeLLo";

    $word = strrev(ucfirst(strrev(strtolower($word))));

    echo $word;
?>
```

Output for all words

```
hellO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'ana-nd';

echo str_replace(substr($string, -3), strtoupper('_'.substr($string, -2)), $string);

// Output: ana_ND


$string = 'anand';

echo str_replace(substr($string, -2), strtoupper(substr($string, -2)), $string);

// Output: anaND
```